# What do you do at the Railroad Camp?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I don't know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try talking to the people there? what does your pardner say?

Answer (score 0):

{EAST}

If you talk to the foreman, he will quit and you'll become the new foreman.  After you become the foreman you can talk to Smee who will tell you how the train is stopped by a pile of rocks and you'll need dynamite to remove them.

Comment: There are several railroad camps, OP has not indicated which one they are stuck on. Your answer only applies to one of them.